# How do I use az cli to create an Azure Monitor Agent on Linux to get free disk space of mount point?

Tags: azure-cli, azure-monitoring

I'm having trouble finding instructions for how to use the az cli to create an Azure Monitor Agent on my Linux VM so I can alert on low available disk space for a mount point (/data). Do I need to create a cron job to write a log file with the available disk space that the monitor can consume? If so, how do I point the monitor to that? This seems more convoluted than it needs to be. Maybe there is a more direct solution?

I had been trying to go down the Diagnostic settings route before I realized 1) it's deprecated and 2) my VMs are running Ubuntu 22.04, which do not support Diagnostic settings.

Comment: If you want to track how much disk space your Linux VM uses with Azure Monitor Agent, follow these steps: 
- Install the agent on your VM as an extension. 
- Make a Data Collection Rule (DCR) that includes disk space and other performance counters. - Create alerts in Azure Monitor that will notify you when your disk space reaches certain levels.

Comment: The questions you answer tend to be about MS Azure configuration, pricing, infrastructure, and other cloud-related issues, instead of being practical programming problems. StackOverflow is meant to discuss only programming questions. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
for more details. Please post your non-programming question on other platforms such as [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)
, and [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/tags/133/azure)
for immediate help. Thanks!